# Fade in, fade out loop via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, fade

I have a img. E.G. [image]

I want some items fade out, fade in in loop on img. Is it possible jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add additional images over the existing one an fade them in and out. The code would look something like this:

```
    <img src='firstStar.jpg' alt='star image' id='firstStar' />

    var loopImages = function(){

         $('#firstStar').fadeIn(1500, function(){

                   $('#firstStar').fadeOut(1500, loopImages);           
         });
    }
    loopImages();
```

Other option might be placing transparent divs over the image and bluring them in a loop. For the later approach you can use [blurjs library.](http://blurjs.com/)

Comment: Rather than using setInterval you should use a self calling function as it allows you more control over the flow. http://jsfiddle.net/RwjFX/

Comment: Thanks Sam, that is a great improvement and prevents potential nasty visual effect in case of bad timing. Updated the answer.

Comment: This won't work because it will call `loopImages()` a zillion times until the stack or memory explodes.  You need to call a subsequent `loopImages()` only when the `fadeOut()` completes.

Answer (score 0):

If you by "some items" refer to some items of the image itself - then the answer is no. But, if you have this image say as a background of some div then you could show some other elements on the image itself (by adding `div`s or `img`s and positioning them accordingly) which would then be fade-in fade-out by jQuery.

Comment: I want create stars effect.